# mysql customizable order by

Tags: php, mysql

i have order by settings in `settings` table and i want to change `order by` with this option, in below sql command i want to use this option if `sortable` field into `settings` is 1 then order by must be `ORDER BY DATE` if `sortable` is 2 then order by must be `ORDER BY ID`.
please help me to have correct sql command

MYSQL:

```
SELECT 
      SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS i.* , 
                     c.title AS category_name, 
                     u.name, 
                     u.family, 
                     s.title AS status_title, 
                     i.thumb_image,
                     CONCAT( u.name, ' ', u.family ) AS author
      FROM   contents i
      JOIN   categories c ON c.id = i.category
      JOIN   users u ON u.id = i.posted_by
      JOIN   status_topics s ON s.id = i.t_status
      WHERE 
      i.portal = 0
              AND (CASE WHEN post_type = 4
                    THEN date(NOW()) BETWEEN i.from_dateTime AND i.to_dateTime 
                   ELSE post_type = 1
                   END)

                  (select sortable from settings) 
                  (case when sortable = 1 then 
                                 ORDER BY topic_date
                  case when sortable = 2 then 
                                 ORDER BY id
                  case when sortable = 3 then 
                                 ORDER BY public
                  end)

                  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Does settings only have one row?

Comment: @Steph Locke, no i want to get that with `SELECT` command and use sortable field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note** answer changed slightly, based on discussion with the OP.

Put the `ORDER BY` *outside* the `CASE`, like this:

```
... the first part of the query, then ...
ORDER BY
  CASE (SELECT sortable FROM settings)
    WHEN 1 THEN topic_date
    WHEN 2 THEN id
    WHEN 3 THEN public
  END
LIMIT 10
```

Note that this will work only if `(SELECT sortable FROM settings)` returns **one** row. If it returns more than one row there will be an error. If it returns zero rows there won't be an error, but none of the sorting options will be chosen - it'll be the same as saying `ORDER BY NULL`.

Comment: Beat me to it, only addition is you'll need to join the sortable table.

Comment: Agreed, but I wasn't quite sure how to do that with the information available so I wimped out with the `first part of the query ...` bit instead :)

Comment: @Ed Gibbs, thanks, i get error this part of sql: `(select sortable from settings) 
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN sortable = 1 THEN topic_date
    WHEN sortable = 2 THEN id
    WHEN sortable = 3 THEN public
  END
LIMIT 10`

Comment: Sorry mahdi - I thought the `(select sortable from settings)` was pseudocode. My bad; I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs, tanks for update post, i get this error now`#1054 - Unknown column 'sortable' in 'order clause'`. i have sortable in settings table

Comment: Does your `settings` table have a column named `sortable`?

Comment: @EdGibbs , yes `settings` table have sortable field, i tested it.SCREEN SHOT: http://www.upload.tehran98.com/img1/8cmwxcjwn8acaa2qanj6.png

Comment: Are you using the very latest answer? It's the one that references `sortable` just once, in the subquery. It's important you use that one: `CASE (SELECT sortable FROM settings) WHEN 1 THEN topic_date WHEN 2 THEN id...`.

Comment: @EdGibbs,yes i'm sure, `ORDER BY
  CASE (SELECT sortable FROM settings)
    WHEN sortable = 1 THEN id
    WHEN sortable = 2 THEN date_time
  END
LIMIT 10`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31679/discussion-between-mahdi-pishguy-and-ed-gibbs)